# How to get widget's HTML without CKEDITOR data attributes

Tags: ckeditor

In a widget's init function I can access the widget's inner HTML using

```
this.element.getHtml();
```

This HTML might contain widget data attributes like `data-cke-enter-mode="1" data-cke-widget-editable="text"`.

I want to get the HTML without these data attributes, exactly the same as the source area/dialog would show it. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it trough the [data processor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor):

```
editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat( widget.wrapper.getOuterHtml() );
```

And in case of an inline widget:

```
editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat( widget.wrapper.getOuterHtml(), { context: 'p' } );
```

Passing the context will prevent auto-paragraphing (inline widget will not be wrapped with a `<p>`).

Comment: I get this error : `TypeError: toBeDowncasted[(toBeDowncasted.length - 1)] is undefined
Stack trace:
setupWidgetsLifecycleEnd/</<@http://localhost:8080/static/lib/ckeditor/plugins/widget/plugin.js:2519:6`
In the widget's `init`, I call: `editor.dataProcessor.toDataFormat(this.wrapper.getOuterHtml());`

Comment: I guess it's a little more complicated. Is it even possible to change the widget's HTML (data format) using a widget dialog? I tried to change widget.element, but now I see that it's defined as readonly in the docs.

Comment: You cannot change widget.element. You can add/remove atrributes to it or change its content, but not itself.

Comment: As for the code - it works for me and it's more or less what happens inside editor.getData(). Could you create a jsfiddle showing the error?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc2kky3k/
I get different exceptions when using Chromium. Guess the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: You overcomplicated this. I wouldn't have thought that you're trying to do this in widget's init callback :D. At that point widget is not fully initialised yet, so it cannot be downcasted. If you try to do this later it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc2kky3k/2/. And you cannot set wrapper's HTML as you tried to do in the data callback. The widget element must be left intact, otherwise you have to reinitialise the widget (which isn't trivial). Plus there are nested editables which must be initialised too. Think about using `editor.insertHtml()` to replace the old widget with a new one.